# why it is not taking 100% height in material design?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-design

Hi could you please tell me why it is not taking 100% height in material design ?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/m34pw4km2x

```
 toolbar__logo: {
    backgroundColor: "#db3131",
    width: "250px",
    height: "100%"
  }
```

react code

```
<Fragment>
        <AppBar position="static" className={classes.mainHeader}>
          <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar__logo}>a</div>
            <div>b</div>
            <div>c</div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Fragment>
```

Expected code

**“Text a”  will cover whole height of parent `div`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
toolbar__logo: {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #db3131;
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

Use this code, please. hope it will be useful for you.
The same solution like @Abhishek Anand already posted below.
you are using a flex property so you show give CSS property align-self:stretch; to the child element

Answer (score 0):

height: "100%" doesn't work on relative/static/absolute positioned elements. It will however work on fixed elements.

```
height: "100%"
position: fixed;
```

another option if you dont want it to be fixed position is to use view height (vh):

```
height: 100vh
```

Comment: I need to cover only `header` 100% not whole window

Comment: @Pixelomo What do you mean with 'doesn't work on relative/static/absolute positioned elements'? If you add `position: absolute` on the element with class 'toolbar__logo' the div with text 'a' actually will cover whole height of parent div.

Comment: it is using flex model so I think we need to use flex properties

Comment: @user944513 If you add to the class '.toolbar__logo' this property `align-self: stretch` will fill the parent element according to this flex documentation I'm using frequently https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . P.S. In your snippet I've write the code like this `"align-self": "stretch"`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not taking 100% height is because it's not a parent element. The height in `%` for a child element will only work if the `height` of parent is defined in `px`. You can check it by adding height for `toolbar` in your index.js:

```
toolbar: {
padding: 0,
height: "200px"
}
```

Similarly, if you want the height of `toolbar` in `%`, fix the height for its parent

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a flex property, you need to set `align-self: stretch;` to the child element
. updated your css value of `"alignSelf"` property.

```
toolbar__logo: {
  backgroundColor: "#db3131",
  alignSelf: stretch;
}
```